# Spring 4.0 WebSocket example-application: Fails to establish websocket connection

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, websocket

I am trying to get the Spring 4 example webapp with websockets (available on [github](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio)) up and running. But I cannot get a websocket connection established.

I am deploying from STS-3.3.0 on a Tomcat-7.0.50 and everything seems to be fine on the server side. After having been successfully logged in as a User, the **message broker is publishing** messages. But the **client fails to connect** to the service!

1.Error message in the browser (originating from sockjs.js):

[image]

2.Console output during login request:

```
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test/]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /index.html
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/index.html]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/index.html] are [/[*][*]]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/index.html] are {}
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/index.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@582e240a] and 1 interceptor
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/test/] is: -1
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css] are [/[*][*]]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css] are {}
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@582e240a] and 1 interceptor
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/test/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css] is: -1
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test/assets/common/portfolio.css]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /assets/common/portfolio.css
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/assets/common/portfolio.css]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/assets/common/portfolio.css] are [/[*][*]]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/assets/common/portfolio.css] are {}
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/assets/common/portfolio.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@582e240a] and 1 interceptor
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/test/assets/common/portfolio.css] is: -1
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png] are [/[*][*]]
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png] are {}
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@582e240a] and 1 interceptor
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/test/assets/lib/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png] is: -1
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:01:10 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

3.Console output after login request is completed:

```
09:43:36 [MessageBrokerSockJS-1] ExecutorSubscribableChannel - [brokerChannel] sending message id=877832f6-d472-8b43-1cd2-555165a7bf4f
09:43:36 [MessageBrokerSockJS-1] ChannelInterceptorChain - postSend (sent=true) message id 877832f6-d472-8b43-1cd2-555165a7bf4f
09:43:36 [brokerChannel-1] DefaultUserDestinationResolver - Ignoring message to /topic/price.stock.RHT, not a "user" destination
09:43:36 [brokerChannel-1] DefaultSubscriptionRegistry - Found 0 subscriptions for destination=/topic/price.stock.RHT
```

I first thought Tomcat was the problem as I read version 7.0.47+ is required. But updating didnt have the desired effect. I am quite new to Web-development, especially to WebSockets, so any help to solve my issue is greatly appreciated. Probably it's only a minor problem as i might have something overseen in configuration due to lacking experience ...

Comment: I seem to remember that it's forced anyway, but I'll double-check. When loading the web page, are you being routed through the login screen? This sets up a user session and that user gets a channel to which portfolio changes are routed.

Comment: btw ... Did you get it working with Jetty first? That project comes configured to use the Maven Jetty plugin. Just run `mvn install jetty:run` from the command-line.

Comment: Yes. I am able to log in. But my user does not subscribe to that channel (as you can see in the log). I have not tried Jetty yet. As i said I am new to web-development, so I only worked with Tomcat so far ... but I will try that out for sure.

Comment: actually it works just fine with jetty ... if you have any idea why it is not working with tomcat though and you post an answer to my question i will accept it. Thank you :-)

Comment: Given that the application works in the embedded Jetty, there's clearly something up with your Tomcat install. Note that Tomcat 7 must be running under Java 7 for websockets to work. Also, the project itself tries to deploy to Tomcat 8. Any chance of trying with Tomcat 8?

Comment: The above log output shows a message being sent with no target subscribers. What happens earlier to the subscriptions after the user logs in?

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev I updated my answer with the full logging that takes place during login-request

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. By "after the user logs in" I meant when the stock portfolio page is loaded. There should be STOMP CONNECT and SUBSCRIBE frames in the server log.

Comment: If you do mean the tomcat server logs (localhost_access_log.[date].txt) there is neither CONNECT nor SUBSCRIBE appearing ... whatever is logged via sysout is shown in my question ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer as such, but it should get you up and running with the example web app on Tomcat and may help diagnose your own Tomcat config. Put the following in your pom.xml next to the `jetty-maven-plugin` config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now from the command-line, you can run:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

or when it has been built, just:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

This will run the application in an embedded Tomcat 7 server. Assuming that works for you (it does for me), then it may be worth looking at your Tomcat version or config and comparing.

Comment: I will have a look at that later in the day. Thank you!

Comment: On the embedded Tomcat it is also running (version is 7.0.30) ... puzzling to me

Comment: I've added the Tomcat maven plugin to the sample. Version 2.2 of the plugin seems to be using Tomcat 7.0.47.

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially caused by conflicting jars in your `webapp` and `tomcat`.
 If you have any tomcat or websocket specific jars that you are including in your build and that end up in the `{TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/{YOUR_WEBAPP}/WEB-INF/lib` directory, they may be causing the conflict with `jars` in the {TOMCAT_HOME}/lib directory. Keep in mind that the jars might not be named precisely the same. I experienced this exact problem before and removing the duplicate jars from the `{TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/{YOUR_WEBAPP}/WEB-INF/lib directory` fixed the 404 error.

As a further note, if you are using gradle to compile your webapp with the 'war' plugin, there is a 'providedCompile' dependency that you can use that will put the necessary jars on your classpath for testing, importing into eclipse, etc. but will not include them in the actual built war (to specifically avoid scenarios like this)